# How to drop orphaned tables in RDS

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, amazon-rds

I have the following two tables that were created due to a sql restart while doing an `alter table` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES WHERE NAME LIKE '%#sql%';

TABLE_ID    NAME    FLAG    N_COLS  SPACE   FILE_FORMAT ROW_FORMAT  ZIP_PAGE_SIZE
1674    avails/#sql-ib1647  1   10  1396    Antelope    Compact 0
1673    avails/#sql-ib1672  1   13  1395    Antelope    Compact 0
```

How do I drop these two tables? When I do:

```
DROP TABLE `#sql-ib1647`
```

I get an error that says `Unknown table 'avails.#sql-ib1647'`. This is a table in Amazon RDS.

Here is a post on the issue: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=570645.

Comment: Could you rename the table using alter table and try? please let me know If it works!!

Comment: @ShivaShinde could you please show a query of what you mean?

Comment: @ShivaShinde I still get a table doesn't exist...

Comment: please try the below answer and let me know please!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**MySQL DOCS:**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html)

Prefix the table with  `#mysql50#`this should solve the problem.

```
DROP TABLE `#sql-ib1647`;
ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table '#sql-ib1647'
```

Instead prefix the filename with #mysql50#, tis should work:

```
DROP TABLE `#mysql50##sql-ib1647`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

> That's because MySQL and MariaDB encode special characters for the
>   filesystem. The trick here is to prefix the tablename with #mysql50#
>   to prevent the server from escaping the hash mark and hyphen:

Comment: The backtics are probably also required.

Comment: @Shiva yes, this was actually the first thing I tried looking at the docs, and I get the same issue. The (only) was I was able to solve the problem is clone the table, and remove the previous table.

Comment: @David542 Yes exactly the docs are suggesting the same. So, finally you were able to drop those orphaned tables?

Comment: @RickJames I didn't get you, could you expand a bit? I already have backtics right?

Comment: It was a minor issue..  You have the backtics -- good.  I was adding the emphasis that they are necessary.  Many people leave them off unless there is a reason to include them.

Comment: This does not work for me. I am still getting:
ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'Web.#mysql150##sql-ib730'

Comment: When I try this on RDS MySQL 5.7 I get: `Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'information_schema'`

Comment: @Mat were you able to find a workaround for this?

Comment: Hi @Amir I don't work any more in the company where we had this issue. Until I left we didn't find a solution unfortunatelly..

Comment: Thanks, @Mat. After reading a few posts, it seems that only AWS Support can delete the orphaned file.

Comment: I'm not able to drop the table: 
 ```SQL
MySQL [test]> create table `#mysql50##sql-ib11691-2823704130` (id int) engine=innodb;
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table '`test`.`#sql-ib11691-2823704130`' already exists
MySQL [test]> drop table `#mysql50##sql-ib11691-2823704130`;
ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'test.#mysql50##sql-ib11691-2823704130'
MySQL [test]> drop table `#sql-ib11691-2823704130`;
ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'test.#sql-ib11691-2823704130'
```

Comment: FWIW, I engaged with AWS support to try and get them to delete these orphaned tables. After days-long runaround, they still didn't delete them, and instead suggested some other "solutions" that still didn't work. I dropped the issue at the time, thinking it was more trouble than it was worth.